# Initialize data with props without making it reactive

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to initialize an object in the data section data with a props object without making it reactive to the prop object itself?
I still want the object in the data section (currentUser) to be reactive to the view.

```
<template>
        <div>
         {{ currentUser.name }}
        </div>
    </template>

props: {
    user: Object,
  },
 data() {
    return {
      currentUser: {
         name: user.name
      }
    };
  },
```

Comment: Can you clarify? What do you want to have happen when the parent changes the user prop's properties?

Comment: Nothing. I just need it for initialization only.

Comment: age old, `currentUser: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.user))`

Comment: From my experience, after initialization from the prop, the child data will not react to parent changes of prop unless you set up a watch on the prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create local data that the component doesn't modify...

```
  props: {
    user: Object,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      userAsMounted,
    };
  },
```

Copy the prop at the time you want it to stop being reactive. (For the whole time, at mounted)...

```
  mounted() {
    Object.assign(this.userAsMounted, this.user)
  },
```

Refer to the copy...

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ userAsMounted.name }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't disable reactivity, but you can control how/when the `data` in your component is set.

Specifically, you can use one of the initialization [life-cycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) to set a data variable with the initial value passed to a prop:

```js
// Will only be run when the component is created.
created() {
  const { user } = this;
  this.currentUser = user;
  // You could also use `this.currentUser = {...user};` 
  //  (accomplishes the same thing as Object.assign), but vue won't react 
  //  when modifying sub-properties of a reactive object within a component.
},
```

If the `user` prop is not set when `created` is run, you might try conditionally setting it in the `updated` hook:

```js
updated() {
  const { currentUser, user } = this;
  // Only set current user if it has not yet been set.
  if (!currentUser) {
    this.currentUser = user;
  }
},
```